# how to foreach 2 array

Tags: php, arrays

i use preg_match_all and get array like this

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => link1
            [1] => link2
            [2] => link3
            [3] => link4
            [4] => link5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => title1
            [1] => title2
            [2] => title3
            [3] => title4
            [4] => title5
        )

)
```

I tried using array_merge, but that's not what I wanted

i want the foreach return like this

```
<a href="link1" class=list-group-item> title1</a>
<a href="link2" class=list-group-item> title2</a>
<a href="link3" class=list-group-item> title3</a>
<a href="link4" class=list-group-item> title4</a>
<a href="link5" class=list-group-item> title5</a>
```

How can i do that???

Comment: Anything you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, reset the keys of your main array.

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Next, loop through one set of your data, in my example I will use the first set of data. Inside the loop, you can grab the 2nd set of data using the key from the first set.

```
foreach($array[0] as $key => $href) {
    $title = $array[1][$key];
    echo "<a href='$href' class=list-group-item> $title</a>";
}
```

This will only work if you always receive 2 sets of data that are the same length.

---

If you don't want to use that method for whatever reason, you could use `array_shift();`.

```
$links = array_shift($array); //grab first set from array, and remove it from array.
$titles = array_shift($array);

foreach($links as $key => $link) {
    $title = $titles[$key];
    echo "<a href='$link' class=list-group-item> $title</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To loop two arrays together independent of its indexes use such construction

```
foreach(array_map(null, ...$arr) as [$link,$title]) {
   echo "<a href='$link' class=list-group-item> $title</a>";
```

Before PHP 7 you need rewrite it to `as list($link,$title)`

Comment: Oh, that's pretty interesting. But wouldn't `array_map()` be executed on every loop? Could that potentially make execution time slower?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It don't think so.

Comment: I vaguely remember reading somewhere that anything inside the foreach loop init is executed on every loop, but that could be wrong/misunderstanding for sure.

Comment: It can be tested easy :)

Comment: Regardless, it's an interesting solution to the problem that I've never seen before, and any amount of slowness from it is probably inconsequential/micro-optimization.

Answer (score 0):

```
$keys=$array[1];

$values=$array[3];


$combines=array_combine($keys,$values);
foreach($combines as $key=>$value)
{
   echo '<a href="'.$key.'" class=list-group-item> '.$value.'</a>';

}
```

Comment: Note: This doesn't work if the keys for the main array are different.

Comment: Off course I except retrieved standard data every time

Comment: @dılosürücü It doesn't seem like a good idea to expect "standard data" in a dynamic language like PHP. Those keys could easily be different every time depending on the method of generating the array.